What is lseek of a tty on macOS doing?
Consider the following C program, named weird.c (because the thing it is doing makes no sense):
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    off_t result = lseek(STDOUT_FILENO, (off_t)INT64_MAX, SEEK_SET);
    if (result != (off_t)-1)
        printf("Seek successful to position %" PRId64 "\n", (int64_t)INT64_MAX);
    else
        perror("lseek failed");
    return 0;
}

Compile and run it from your terminal window, e.g. gcc -o weird weird.c && ./weird. It is important you are running it from a tty (terminal window, SSH session, etc), so stdout is a tty.
On Linux, it will fail with the error lseek failed: Illegal seek–which makes sense, seeking on a tty doesn't make much sense.
However, on macOS it behaves differently – the program exits without printing anything, and then – if you are using bash as your shell, the shell exits too. (By contrast, if you are using zsh as your shell, your shell prompt still works, but no commands display any output.) I can only assume this is because the tty has been put into some sort of illegal state. But what is actually going on here?
I was guessing macOS would behave similarly to FreeBSD. But FreeBSD 14.1-RELEASE (amd64) has a different behaviour again–it prints:
Seek successful to position 9223372036854775807

Which is more understandable than what macOS does (treating nonsensical operation as a no-op instead of erroring out on it like Linux does.)

Why do you output INT64_MAX there?

Weird indeed!  I can reproduce it (M3 MacBook Pro running macOS Sonoma 14..61).
After running the program, echo $?, or ls, or ps produces no output — and lldb appears to hang.  I ended up manually closing the window.
Change the offset to 0, or 100000000, and the (modified) program reports success without locking everything up.  man lseek stipulates that ESPIPE ("Illegal seek") will be returned if the file descriptor is associated with a pipe, socket, or FIFO.   Neither man -s 4 tty nor man -s 4 pty provides me with any illumination.

BTW, if you break stdout, you can't see any printf() output any more. For debugging, I'd write such output to a file and run tail -f in a second terminal on it.

Just to clarify Linux's behaviour, using lseek on a terminal device is well-documented here: "On Linux, using lseek() on a terminal device returns ESPIPE."

Tried this on Win10 with MinGW 13.2.0, it produced the same result as your Linux experiment.

POSIX says: The behavior of lseek() on devices which are incapable of seeking is implementation-defined. The value of the file offset associated with such a device is undefined.

The MacOS manual page for lseek seems to be this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/lseek.2.html (even though it says iPhoneOS).  That says only "Some devices are incapable of seeking.  The value of the pointer associated with such a device is undefined."  I guess that could be read to indicate that the behavior in MacOS is undefined.

MacOS being a BSD derivative, it may be worthwhile to consider what the BSD manual page has to say about it (in the Bugs section): "If  the lseek() system call is operating on a device which is incapable of seeking [other than a pipe, socket, or FIFO], it will request the seek operation and return successfully, even though no seek was performed.  Because the offset argument will be stored unconditionally in the file descriptor of that device, there  is no  way to confirm if the seek operation succeeded or not [...]."

@JohnBollinger That MacOS man page puzzled me. Can implementation-defined behavior be undefined? The nasty effects on the TTY seem like a system bug. What if this was done on the system console in single user mode (if such a thing exists in MacOS)?

@IanAbbott, I don't think it's conforming for an implementation to fail to define implementation defined behavior, whether implicitly or explicitly.  It may be that there's some other place that MacOS defines this particular behavior, but I think it more likely that it just fails to conform in this regard.

@IanAbbott Since terminal emulators and SSH sessions use ptys, while the console uses a real terminal device of some kind, I suspect the behavior is totally different in the two cases.

The Linux and Windows behavior is the expected result. I agree that it seems to be a bug in MacOS.

Does it only happen with INT64_MAX, or with any offset value?

@Barmar Perhaps you are correct about the two cases, but on Linux the file operations for all TTY types go through a common TTY subsystem layer.

@IanAbbott The behaviour is the same for all ttys, on both Linux and macOS. On Linux, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.10/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L465 hardcodes llseek for all ttys to no_llseek, disabling seeking. A tty driver supplies a struct tty_operations whose members are functions to perform certain operations, but seeking is not one of them. Conversely, the EFBIG when write_offset == INT64_MAX on macOS 11+ is happening in VFS code so applies to all files/devices, it is not in any way tty-specific.

User jepler on Hacker News pointed out the explanation.
Notice this code in the vn_write function in bsd/vfs/vfs_vnops.c:
        if (write_offset == INT64_MAX) {
                /* writes are not possible */
                error = EFBIG;
                goto error_out;
        }

Basically what happens is this:

macOS, unlike Linux, lets you use lseek to set the offset of a terminal – even though (usually) the offset doesn't actually do anything
However, once the offset reaches INT64_MAX, further attempts to write fail with EFBIG, unless you seek back to somewhere earlier.

The reason why bash exits, is most shells exit when they can't write to stdout/stderr. As to why zsh doesn't, I'm not sure, but I speculate the zsh line editing code is opening the terminal device directly, and hence accesses it with an independent file position.
If you modify my test program to seek to e.g. INT64_MAX-100, you will be able to print 100 bytes of output, before all output starts failing.
This code appears to have been introduced in xnu-7195.50.7.100.1 (macOS 11 Big Sur) – it wasn't present in xnu-6153.11.26 (macOS 10.15 Catalina).
FreeBSD also appears to allow you to lseek to arbitrary offsets in a terminal – but unlike macOS 11+, won't refuse further writes if you seek up to INT64_MAX.

I suspect this was intended as a sanity check, "should never get here". It's not like there's a good reason to seek this far in a terminal (or any real file, either).
